# CKEDITOR - cannot edit text or use any of the buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a div that when clicked will open up the CKEDITOR. I want the contents of the div to be loaded into the editor. When i click off the editor i want the contents of the editor to be displayed in the div.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var editor;
    $(function () {
        if (editor != null) {
            editor.destroy(true);
        }
        else {
            editor = null;
        }

        editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

       $('.textObj').on('dblclick', function () {
          $('#cke_editor1').show();       
          $("#cke_1_contents").html($('.textObj').html());
       })
       $('#cke_1_top').on('dblclick', function () {
          $('.textObj').html($('#cke_1_contents').html());
          $('#cke_editor1').hide();
       })
</script>

<div class="textObj">Here is some Text</div>
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
```

When i double click the div it opens the editor as expected and the editor does contain the text from the div. However i am not able to edit the text and when i click on one of the buttons i get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to have both the textarea and the div?

Use [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/inlineall.html) inline editing.

Remove the textarea.

Add contenteditable="true" to the div.

Comment: Link leads to 404